# Saving image overwrite in sdcard android

Tags: android, image, sd-card, save, overwrite

i'm using the following code for saving the image

```
        FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
            //  File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //  File file = new File(root, "androidlife.jpg");
//              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//                        + File.separator + "/test.jpg");
                Random fCount = new Random();
                // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Comment by Lucifer
                  int roll = fCount.nextInt(600) + 1;
                  //System.out.println(roll);


                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "/test" + String.valueOf(roll) +".jpg" );

                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainLayout.getWidth(),
                        mainLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                mainLayout.draw(c);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    if (fos != null) {
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            //  }  Comment by Lucifer
```

it save the image perfectly but overwrite when i press the save button twice...What can be the issue? Any sugestion??

Comment: what exactly do you want/expect to happen when you press the button second time?

Comment: @Lucifer i've tried your ans, it saves the image 5 times on a single click, and saving in the root folder

Comment: can you upload your updated code please ?

Comment: @Lucifer find my updated code!!!!

Comment: why you are using for loop, just remove it and your code it ready dear

Comment: I have updated your code please check it @user1296361, see my comments in your code at two please, now run this code, your problem will 100% get solve

Comment: @Lucifer it is saving in the root folder, what to do to change its path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given a static file name.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "/test.jpg");
```

So, Everytime it is going to create a image with test.jpg name and at a same location. The only logic you need to implement is to change your file name to be a dynamic file name. You can try it in this way

static int fCount = 0;

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "/test" + String.valueOf(fCount++) +".jpg" );
```

Now above line is going to create a new file every time, starting with name test0.jpg, test1.jpg ... and so on.

But this could create a problem when you close your application and restart your application. Because it will going to start again from 0 counter.

So i suggest you to go with a random number contacatination with file name.

Answer (score 6):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "/test.jpg");
if(!file.exists()){
    try {
      file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    file.delete();
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainLayout.getWidth(),
mainLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
mainLayout.draw(c);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    if (fos != null) {
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: see the above instead of overworting you can delete the file if exists and recreate the new one. also if you dont want create new file if it exist then simply write your code in if block and remove else block.

Comment: i want to create the new file every time on a single click, it should neither over write nor delete the previous one

Comment: Thanks that's work for me..i have old file deleted and create new file that's perfact work thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

sticker_view.setLocked(true);

```
        sticker_view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = sticker_view.getDrawingCache();
        Log.e("BITMAP", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + bitmap);

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File newDir = new File(root + "/Edited Image");
        newDir.mkdirs();

        Random gen = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = gen.nextInt(n);
        String photoName = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        Log.e("PHOTONAME", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + photoName);

        File file = new File(newDir, photoName);
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("FILEPATH", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + filePath);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "Image Already Exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            file.delete();
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.e("OUT", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + out);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            bitmap.recycle();

            Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "Saved In Edited Image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            item.setVisible(false);

            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(EditActivity.this, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
                    null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("URI");
            intent.putExtra("uri", filePath);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack. Overflow. 

An explanation of why this fixes the original problem would be very helpful. What error did the OP make?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the name of your file name to get a complete unique file name. This will add current time in milliseconds since epoch to your file name and unless you can create more than one file in a single millisecond, no overwrite will be done.